# What is the allowed Text field limit or length?

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme

I have a schema with a normal "Text" field (content field not metadata) which sets with "50" rows. (Also, tried with maximum rows 99) (Not an Rich Text field).

Trying to create a component based on this schema, and copied and pasted a code snippet around 30000 lines (around 2 MB).

when i save the component getting below error in CME

> /WebUI/Models/TCM54/Services/General.svc/SaveNewItem failed to execute. STATUS (413): Request Entity Too Large

What is the maximum number of character/byte can be pasted in the normal text field? if there is any setting needs to be done for this in CME can you point me the place/file to do so?

regards
Jey

Comment: I suspect that there wouldn't be a max size specifically for text fields but there will be a max size for the whole component XML. Probably it's related to the field definition in the CM database.

Comment: It does sound highly unusual to store a code snippet of that size in a text field in a CMS. Is this a technical exercise, something that you're trying to make work with an existing implementation or something else?

Comment: I agree, it may be the whole component, i have only one filed in the schema. I agree, it is unusual to store this size code snippet, this is one of the exception which i have. Before i go for other option, i would like to see is it possible to store this much size in a component. if yes, how to solve this size error.

Answer (score 5):

By default, there is mo constraint on the length/size of a text field. It is technically possible to put a constraint in the Schema, but you will have to manually edit the XSD for that purpose (the Schema GUI doesn't support field constraints).

However, the error you are getting occurs even before (server-side) Schema validation happens; the total size of the HTTP request is larger than WCF likes. This is a general security measure against Denial of Service attacks.

Comment: Hi Rick, where can i adjust to make this work? in IIS

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2015/08/21/large-file-upload-failure-for-web-application-calling-wcf-service-413-request-entity-too-large/

Comment: Or, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26723894/413-request-entity-too-large